# Time difference With 0 Values

Tags: google-sheets, time, sum, google-sheets-formula, forecast

Im having a problem in google sheets. I want to sum 2 columns the time that a driver is driving without the stops. So im using this formula to do it:

[image]

[image]

G7 is 10:20 value and H6 is 10:00.

But I want to do it in all the lines, but when I use the same formula:

[image]

I get this value:

[image]

Any idea how can I ignore the zero values that are making my database giving me wrong values when in this example the result I want is 00:40. The time driving without the unloads?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_fRQetAhiYhuuY4Az4og_lP3nrKzkBUVCoHU8X_CUFA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=TEXT(SUMPRODUCT(IF(G7:G20="";;G7:G20-H6:H19)); "[h]:mm")
```

[image]